# Laser Animation with TweenJS and EaselJS

Tags: javascript, easeljs, tween

So, I'm trying to create a laser effect, similar to the one located at http://map.norsecorp.com/

For this example, I have a 500x500 canvas. The current javascript part of the solution is located below:

```
function shootLaser(x, y) {
  var beam = new createjs.Shape();

  beam.graphics.beginFill("red");
  beam.graphics.moveTo(0,1.5).lineTo(70,0).lineTo(70,3).closePath();
  beam.x = 80;
  beam.y = 50;
  stage.addChild(beam);

  beam.setBounds(0,0,70,3);
  createjs.Tween.get(beam,{ loop: true, onChange: beamUpdate })
    .to({ x: 400 }, 1000, createjs.Ease.linear());
}

function beamUpdate(e) {
  var beam = e.currentTarget.target;
  var targetX = e.currentTarget._curQueueProps.x;

  if( targetX - beam.x < beam.getBounds().width ) {
    beam.scaleX = (targetX - beam.x) / targetX;
  } else {
    beam.scaleX = 1;
  }
}
```

This draws the line the way that I want to. However the scaleX method doesn't quite work (not even close really, it just gets extremely small very fast).

The problem is that I can't find a way to shrink the "laser" once it hits it's target. If I shoot it from 0px to 250px. It should hit 250px and begin shrinking until the 250th pixel has "consumed" it for lack of a better term. Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm also open to doing this with other libraries or tools. I just haven't found them yet.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ytgn8frr/ -- Any reason you don't just mask it instead of scaling it? http://jsfiddle.net/trdkccu1/

Comment: Ah, well done. I've not played with many graphic projects. Using the mask was perfect. I'd accept that as the answer if it wasn't a comment.